# Amazon S3 Pending Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After deleting a bucket to reconfigure its properties, the bucket continued to show as 'Not found' I assume it was deleted, but I am not able to create a bucket with the same name due to it already existing.

Steps for deleting:

1. Removed all dependencies pointing to S3 bucket content
2. Deleted all content within S3 Bucket
3. Deleted bucket

Is this a bug or a common issue?

Note: To see if it was caching, waited a few hours since the bucket was deleted.

[image: Bucket Object]

Comment: This is quite common. Just wait 24-48 hours and it will disappear completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon is somewhat ambiguous about the policy for bucket name re-use. From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/BucketRestrictions.html

> Reusing bucket names
>
> If a bucket is empty, you can delete it. After a bucket is deleted,
> the name becomes available for reuse. However, after you delete the
> bucket, you might not be able to reuse the name for various reasons.
>
> For example, when you delete the bucket and the name becomes available
> for reuse, another AWS account might create a bucket with that name.
> In addition, **some time might pass before you can reuse the name of a
> deleted bucket**. If you want to use the same bucket name, we recommend
> that you don't delete the bucket.